# Order by ID if two users have same number of credits

Tags: php, mysql

:-)
I have this script, which find a users position taken from the number of credits.
It all works, but i have a little problem. If two users have the same credits, both of them will be on the same position.
Can I do, so if there are more users with same credits, then the system need to order by the users ID and out from that give them a position?

This is my code so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS `number`
        FROM `users` 
        WHERE `penge` > 
                       (SELECT `penge` FROM `users` 
                        WHERE `facebook_id` = ".$facebook_uid.")";
$query_rang = $this->db->query($sql);
```

So if i have this:

```
ID -------- Credits

1  -------- 100

2  -------- 100

3  -------- 120
```

Then the rank list should be like this:

Number 1 is user with ID 3

Number 2 is user with ID 1

Number 3 is user with ID 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS `number` FROM `users` WHERE `penge` > (SELECT `penge` FROM `users` WHERE `facebook_id` = ".$facebook_uid.") ORDER BY COUNT(*) + 1 desc, users.ID";
$query_rang = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Later EDIT:

I don't understand why you still have the same results....

I made a quick test. I have created a table:

Test: ID (Integer) and No (Integer)

I have inserted some values:

```
id  no
1   1
1   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
4   1
5   1
```

Now, if I run:

```
SELECT 
  id, COUNT(*) + 1 AS `number`
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
  id
```

I get:

```
id  number
1   4
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   2
```

But if I add ORDER BY:

```
SELECT 
  id, COUNT(*) + 1 AS `number`
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
  id
ORDER BY 
  count(*) desc, id
```

then I get:

```
id  number
1   4
4   3
2   2
3   2
5   2
```

Comment: +1. But that `+1` after `COUNT(*)` in the `ORDER BY` made me laugh really loud :D

Comment: It returns the same as before :(

Comment: In you example it looks it it is working. But i only get a print out with the output "2" on everything i do. You can see my example here: http://pastebin.com/vYgr57G4

Answer (score 6):

`ORDER BY credits DESC, id ASC`.  This will sort by credits and break ties with the id.

- UPDATE

I understand now that you want the ranking information for the user, not just to sort the users by credits and ids. This will give you the complete list of users and their rankings:

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, users.id, users.facebook_id FROM users, (SELECT @rank:=0) dummy ORDER BY penge DESC, id ASC
```

Getting the row number is the tricky bit solved by this blog post:
http://jimmod.com/blog/2008/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/

Comment: The same result as before :(
I just added you extension to the end of my select?